# Monte-Carlo error Confidence Intervals

Tags: bootstrap, monte-carlo, error

I am constructing 95% confidence intervals on some metric of interest using MC simulation. These intervals can be constructed for example using bootstrapping.

Does it mean that if I repeat the same MC simulation 100 times with a different seed, 95% of my results should be inside the confidence interval?

Comment: No, it means that n repeated sampling approximately 95% of the intervals will contain the true value of the unknown parameter(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$[a,b]$ is a 95%CI if probability that true vaule of your metric lies between $a$ and $b$ is 95%.

In statistics, we believe that a thing called 'true value' actually exists (given by God, Nature, Spaghetti Monster or who/what-ever). We are aware that we can never tell exact value of it, but we try to approximate it.

So, above definition means, in practice, that if you run your MC simulation $n$ times and obtain $n$ different 95%CIs, $0.95n$ of them should contain true vaule of your metric.

Of course bootstrap CIs are just an approximations of exact CIs that could be calculated if we knew distribution of your metric.

Comment: This is incorrect.

Comment: Why? Isn't it exactly what you wrote (7h later) in your comment?

Comment: @ŁukaszDeryło Saying a 95% confidence interval has a 95% probability of containing the true parameter is incorrect because that's a Bayesian Credible Interval interpretation of a Frequentist Confidence Interval.  With confidence intervals, the "95%" is about the process and how often the limits will contain the true parameter.  You could say that, before generating the confidence limits, the chance that the limits would end up containing the true parameter is 95%, but, once the limits are generated, the  parameter doesn't have a probability of being inside the limits.  It is or isn't inside.